# using Tail Bundle to have vim follow a file

Tags: vim, tail

I'm trying to use vim to follow a file, similarly to how `tail -f` does it.  I want to use vim, because I want the ability to move around the file, search for text, etc while still having the file be followed.

I've found the [Tail Bundle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1714) plugin, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.  None of the commands listed in the [docs](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Tail-Bundle/blob/master/doc/tail.txt) cause the file to continuously load at the bottom.  They simply open the same file in a preview window.

Does anyone know how to use this plugin, or can you provide another way to use vim to follow a file like `tail -f`

Comment: You can ask for help on [the plugin's issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/vim-scripts/issues/list).

Comment: `:set autoread` then type `G` to scroll to the end

Answer (score 0):

I would not use Vim for that. `less` comes with *many* vi-like key-bindings for navigation and is inherently better for use as a pager than Vim.

```
$ less +F filename
$ command | less +F
```

Comment: can a custom vim syntax file be used with less?

Comment: No, but you can use pygments to colorize less if you want.